# Merging Dicts that have Lists of Dicts in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I am trying to merge two `dict`s in Python that could be The same or one could have far less info

ex.

```
master = {"a": 5564, "c": [{"d2":6}]}
daily = { "a": 795, "b": 1337, "c": [{"d1": 2,"d2": 2,"d3": [{"e1": 4,"e2": 4}]}]}
```

They need to be merged so the output is as such

```
master = { "a": 6359, "b": 1337, "c": [{"d1": 2,"d2": 8,"d3": [{"e1": 4,"e2": 4}]}]}
```

I took a shot at it though I only ever get returned null. I might be missing something or just way off. I just cant figure it out. Any help would be amazing Thank you.

```
def merge(master,daily):
    for k, v in daily.items():
        if isinstance(daily[k],list):
            key_check = keyCheck(k, master)
            if key_check:
                merge(master[k],daily[k])
            else :
                master[k] = daily[k]
        else :
            if keyCheck(k, master):
                 master[k] += daily[k]
            else :
                master[k] = daily[k]
```

`keyCheck` only checks if a key is in the dictionary so it doesn't throw errors.

Comment: Are you sure that `master` and `daily` are dictionaries, that every value in dictionaries here is a string or a list, and each list has exactly one item which is a dictionary? And are you sure this will be followed, so no error checking is required?

Comment: Not every value is going to be a list but some are. is there something I am not understanding about dictionaries can they not have different types of values for each key? I am fairly new to python and dictionaries in general.

Comment: Dictionaries can indeed have different types of values for each key: your example uses both strings and lists as values, as I note in my comment. I ask because the code for your answer can be simpler if you are sure that the data follows the same pattern as your example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a one linear using `collections.Counter()`:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>> C2 = Counter(daily)
>>> C1 = Counter(master)
>>> 
>>> {k:reduce(lambda x,y : Counter(x)+Counter(y), v) if isinstance(v, list) and k in (C1.viewkeys() & C2) else v for k, v in (C1 + C2).items()}
{'a': 6359, 'c': Counter({'d3': [{'e1': 4, 'e2': 4}], 'd2': 8, 'd1': 2}), 'b': 1337}
```

First off, you can convert your dictionaries to Counter objects in order to add the values for common keys after summing the counters (that's how Counter's add attribute works), then you can loop over the items and for keys that exist in both counters and their values are lists, you can use the `reduce()` function to apply the same algorithm to all of the list items too.

If your list contains another nested similar data structure, you can convert this code to a recursive function.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Works perfectly even with a large amount of data!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a recursive solution. Though it cannot compete with Kasramvd's answer.

```
def merge(dic1, dic2):

    merged = dict(dic1, **dic2) # Merge dictionaries without adding values. Just exchanging them.
                                # Similar to .update() but does not override subdicts.

    for key in merged:
        if key in dic1 and key in dic2:
            if isinstance(dic1[key], list):
                merged[key] = merge(dic1[key][0], dic2[key][0])
            else:
                merged[key] = dic1[key] + dic2[key]

    return merged
```